# jQuery test if event result is equal to an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's my code :

```
$('html').on("click", function (e) {
    if(!$(e).is($element)) {
        hideResults();
    }
});
```

I tried this, but it does not work. Element is a div. I want to test if the event result is equal to the element.

EDIT
This is updated code, still doesn't work

```
$(document).on("click", function (e) {
    if(!$(e.target).is($element)) {
        hideResults();
    }
});
```

Comment: What is `$element`? How do you get it?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir $element is alright. I have tested to make sure it is defined.

Comment: Try an put an alert inside the if and see if it will pop up!

Comment: not sure if it's good to define an variable starting with $ if you are using jquery, though it may be fine, I'm not sure

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir The if statement does execute. The problem is that it executes when clicking on $element!

Comment: @A.Lau I am pretty sure that you usually define jQuery selectors starting with a dollar sign.

Comment: yes but if you're selecting a variable called `element` you would use `$(element)`, or you would just use `element`, but not `$element`

Comment: @Wyatt does the alert pops up  when clicking on div and outside it too?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Yes

Comment: @Wyatt Can you post an example of your HTML along with the value of `$element`!

Answer (score 2):

You have to check `e.target` not the event itself. Like this:

```
$(document).on("click", function (e) {
    if(!$(e.target).is($element)) {
        hideResults();
    }
});
```

And why using `"html"`, `document` is better!

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I added the updated code, still does not appear to be working.

Answer (score 0):

As of I can only guess what you are trying to accomplish with the result of the click event I am only able to push you in right direction.

**Trying to explain the given code:**
Just to clarify the usage of the jQuery method **on()**: It attaches an event handler to an object. In this case is the object a jQuery object which wraps around the **DOM-Element** . The first parameter is the event you want to occure and should trigger the event handler method as the third parameter which in other words is just a **delegate** or in this case an **anonymous javascript function**. This funciton will get parameters passed into it from the jQuery method **on()**.

**The important part** is that you have to know what is the result of the 'click'-event, you can find it probably here: https://api.jquery.com/click/

If the usage of the method **.on()** is unclear you will find it here: https://api.jquery.com/on/

I hope I could help you!